# No wifi adapter found - Nobara

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I recently switched from Ubuntu to [Nobara](https://nobaraproject.org/) (official version), and I went through the normal setup process and erased the ubuntu partition. After the setup it told me to do a standard reboot (`sudo reboot`), so I did. I then wanted to change the appearance even more so I opened up the terminal and typed `sudo apt update`, but then realised Nobara uses DNF, so I typed in `dnf upgrade` and it gave me an error, I didn't even read the error until I tried again with root `sudo dnf upgrade`. The error said that the repos couldn't be reached, so I opened up settings for the first time and in the internet section it was for wired connections, then I searched for wifi and it showed up and said `wifi adapter not found`.
**Please Help!**